# SQL Server view for calc ParentId column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with following sampled rows:

```
Id CompanyId value
1   X          a
2   X          b
3   X          c
4   X          d
5   Y          e
6   Y          f
7   z          g
8   Z          h
9   X          i
10  X          j
```

I want to have a view with following result :

```
Id CompanyId ParentId
1   X          NULL
2   X          NULL
3   X          NULL
4   X          NULL
5   Y          1
6   Y          1
7   z          5
8   Z          5
9   X          7
10  X          7
```

On this result calculated ParentId for each row. ParentId for each row equal to Id of first row from previous companyId.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that SQL Server 2012 tag is here for reason :)

```
;with x as (
    select *, lag(companyid) over(order by id) as prev
    from #t1
),
y as (
    select *, sum(case when prev = companyid then 0 else 1 end) over(order by id) as grp
    from x
)

select y.id, y.companyid, min(y1.id)
from y 
left join y y1 on y1.grp = y.grp-1
group by y.id, y.companyid
```

Comment: But you did put 2012 tag, didn't you?

Comment: Yes. My develop server is SQL Server 2012 and my operational server is SQL Server 2008R2. I can't move your query from develop database to operational database.